# How to create a TypeScript Nodejs module spanning multiple files

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to create a Node.js module with a single namespace using TypeScript.  I need the classes of the module to be in separate files, and have references to each other.  I also need this module to utilize other node modules.  But if I understand right, TypeScript only supports namespaces if a namespace is contained within a single file or the namespace does not use external modules.

Some people present the use of post-build tools to make the final module work, which is nice but doesn't address all the errors TypeScript throws when combining cross-file namespaces and imports during development.

Is it true that the closest solution is to create a module per file, and create a web of inter-imports?

Comment: I'm not following, as I've got something that sounds very similar working in a Windows App Store WinJs app. I didn't have any problems.

Comment: What I'm presenting is a known issue:
http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/760
http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that what works best for me for module dependencies is to always use source references, e.g.:

```
/// <reference path="other.ts" />
```

Since you can't generate single-file output from tsc if you use language-level imports/modules, I have resorted to using `require` as a function and so on.

This seems to be the [same solution chosen by the TypeScript developers themselves](http://typescript.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/compiler/io.ts) (search for "require(" there). As suggested by silentorb's comment, you can declare the `require` function as some variation of the following (or use [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/node/node.d.ts)):

```
declare function require(name: string): any;
```

Note that there's often a lot of discussion on the whole modularity topic in TS over on the TS forums ([one recent example](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/457293)).

Comment: I wouldn't have understood your explanation by itself, but the first link pointed to demonstrated the solution.

Avoid `import foo = require('foo')`

Override require with `declare var require: any;`

Comment: Could you edit your answer to mention the code I have in my comment?  I've seen this problem talked about several places without anyone presenting that code.  The closest I saw was one sample where they overrode require, but I never understood why because their code didn't use it.

Comment: I put in the `require` declaration that I've used before, although yours is more versatile and the one in DefinitelyTyped is more detailed.

Comment: As an update, I recommend using ES6 modules in TypeScript these days.